# Responsive Carousel, change itemsToShow on mobile in React

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I am trying to make a responsive carousel on React. I want to show 3 items on desktop and 1 item on mobile. So I set 3 to itemsToShow but is there any way that I can set it to 1 on mobile?

```
import React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-elastic-carousel";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

export const SimpleCarousel = () => (
    <Container>
      <div className="carousel">
        <h4 className="title">Title</h4>
        <Carousel itemsToShow={3} focusOnSelect={true}>
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
          <Cart />
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check their docs here https://sag1v.github.io/react-elastic-carousel/

and I believe this is your answer. You have to provide this settings as an array.

[image]